# Python Pandas - Moving Average with uneven period lengths

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to figure out how to deal with time series data in pandas that has uneven period lengths.  The first example I'm looking at is how to calculate a moving average for the last 15 days. Here is an example of the data (time is UTC)

```
index   date_time         data
46701   1/06/2016 19:27   15.00
46702   1/06/2016 19:28   18.25
46703   1/06/2016 19:30   16.50
46704   1/06/2016 19:33   17.20
46705   1/06/2016 19:34   18.18
```

I'm not sure if I should just fill in data so its all even 1 minute increments, or if there is a smarter way...  If anyone has suggestions it would be much appreciated

Thanks - KC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this.

- Resample at the frequency you want (or downsampling)

  - You have to pay attention here to the resampling strategy. It has to be consistent with the meaning of your data. Here I have arbitrary used `bfill` (back fill that use next valid value) but another strategy could be more appropriate like `ffill` (forward fill that propagates the last valid value).
- Compute a moving average.
- Maybe you will have to deal with the index

Note: This syntax for `rolling` has been introduced in [pandas 0.18.0](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html). However it is possible to do the same thing in previous version with `pd.rolling_mean`.

```
# Test data
d = {'data': [15.0, 18.25, 16.5, 17.199999999999999, 18.18],
 'date_time': ['1/06/2016 19:27',
  '1/06/2016 19:28',
  '1/06/2016 19:30',
  '1/06/2016 19:33',
  '1/06/2016 19:34'],
 'index': [46701, 46702, 46703, 46704, 46705]}

df = DataFrame(d)
df['date_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_time'])

# Setting the date as the index
df.set_index('date_time', inplace=True)
# Resampling data
df = df.resample('1T').bfill()
# Performing moving average
df['moving'] = df['data'].rolling(window=3, center=True).mean()
df.plot(y=['data', 'moving'])
df
                      data  index     moving
date_time                                   
2016-01-06 19:27:00  15.00  46701        NaN
2016-01-06 19:28:00  18.25  46702  16.583333
2016-01-06 19:29:00  16.50  46703  17.083333
2016-01-06 19:30:00  16.50  46703  16.733333
2016-01-06 19:31:00  17.20  46704  16.966667
2016-01-06 19:32:00  17.20  46704  17.200000
2016-01-06 19:33:00  17.20  46704  17.526667
2016-01-06 19:34:00  18.18  46705        NaN
```

[image: plot]

### Edit

Here is an example with missing data.

```
# Random data parameters
num_sample = (0, 100)
nb_sample = 1000
start_date = '2016-06-02'
freq = '2T'

random_state = np.random.RandomState(0)

# Generating random data
df = pd.DataFrame({'data': random_state.randint(num_sample[0], num_sample[1], nb_sample)},
                          index=random_state.choice(
                              pd.date_range(start=pd.to_datetime(start_date), periods=nb_sample * 3,
                                            freq=freq),
                              nb_sample))
# Removing duplicate index
df = df.groupby(df.index).first()
# Removing data for closed periods
df.loc[(df.index.hour >= 22) | (df.index.hour <= 7),'data'] = np.nan
# Resampling
df = df.resample('1T').ffill()
# Moving average by hours
df['avg'] = df['data'].rolling(window=60).mean()

ax = df.plot(kind='line', subplots=True)
```

[image]

Comment: Legend - thanks a lot for that.  I'm new at python/pandas, and learned a few things from this post.  Thx

Comment: Cool ! Since pandas has been created at first for financial analysis, it has huge capabilities on time series operations.

Comment: Thanks for the edits, and re: your comment thats what it looks like.   Bit lazy on my side, but does pandas also include econometrics / forecasting capabilities?  I'm trying to find examples online of cool things to do with financial data and pandas, but most things seem to be moving averages etc...

Comment: Sorry - one last question.  Lets say I want to exclude time when the market is closed.  I don't mind backfilling data when the market is open, but I don't want to backfill when the market is closed (because a moving average on it will overweight the dummy data when the market is closed.. i think?)  

Would you just set the df[time between x & y] = NaN?

Comment: First, sorry for my late answer. 
Check this documentation, pandas includes some other features like [exponentially weighted windows](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/computation.html#exponentially-weighted-windows)
However, for more advanced time series analysis you should check the `tsa` package of [StatsModels](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/stable/tsa.html).
I'm not a specialist of stock analysis. I've just edited the answer to include an example of resampling and moving average with missing values. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I'm no specialist either! haha